# NullPointerException Inet6AddressImpl

Tags: java, android, react-native

I have a `react native` app that has an SDK for `custom bridges` to `native code`.
I use this [third party package](https://github.com/stealthcopter/AndroidNetworkTools), this makes my exception.

My app works in real devices and emulator with `Android 9+` and there are no exceptions or something in the logs.
But when I run the app in `8.0` or `8.1 my app throws an exception.

My app has androidX dependencies and the third package doesn't so I don't know if this can be a problem.

Also can be related with the `cleartexttraffic` ? or some permissions that change between the versions.

React native android manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"/>
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
        <service android:name="org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService"></service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

My custom sdk for bridges

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sweeprapitest">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <service android:name="org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService"></service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I expect that my app works with android 8 and here is the exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.io.FileDescriptor.isSocket$()' on a null object reference
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.close(BlockGuardOs.java:91)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.icmpEcho(Inet6AddressImpl.java:270)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.isReachable(Inet6AddressImpl.java:186)
    at java.net.InetAddress.isReachable(InetAddress.java:478)
    at com.stealthcopter.networktools.ping.PingTools.doJavaPing(PingTools.java:74)
    at com.stealthcopter.networktools.ping.PingTools.doPing(PingTools.java:38)
    at com.stealthcopter.networktools.Ping.doPing(Ping.java:162)
    at com.stealthcopter.networktools.SubnetDevices$SubnetDeviceFinderRunnable.run(SubnetDevices.java:223)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```